# Loop to insert data in OleDb breaks when I try to execute more than 1 query

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, oledb

I'm working on a small offline C# application with an Access 2002 database (.mdb) and OleDb.

I have 2 tables where I need to insert data at the same time, one holding a foreign key of the other. So, to simplify let's say one table has 2 attributes: "idTable1" (auto-increment integer) and "number", and the other has 2 attributes: "idTable2" (auto-increment integer) and "fkTable1" (foreign key containing an integer value that matches an "idTable1" from table 1).

A foreach loop iterates over a collection and inserts each element in Table1. Then the idea is to use a `SELECT @@Identity` query on Table1 to get the auto-incrementing id field of the last record that was inserted, and insert that in Table2 as a foreign key.

I'm just trying the first part before I attempt to insert the foreign key: loop over a collection, insert each item in Table1 and get the idTable1 of the last inserted record. But whenever I try to execute `SELECT @@Identity` I get only 1 record in my database, even when the loop correctly iterates over all the collection items.

My code looks like this:

```
string queryInsertTable1 = "INSERT INTO Table1 (numero) VALUES (?)";
string queryGetLastId = "Select @@Identity";

using (OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(strDeConexion))
{
    using (OleDbCommand commandStatement = new OleDbCommand(queryInsertTable1, dbConnection))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();
        foreach (int c in Collection)
        {
            commandStatement.Parameters.AddWithValue("", c);
            commandStatement.ExecuteNonQuery();
            commandStatement.CommandText = queryGetLastId;
            LastInsertedId = (int)commandStatement.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out the last 3 lines:

```
commandStatement.CommandText = queryGetLastId;
LastInsertedId = (int)commandStatement.ExecuteScalar();
```

Then all records from Collection are correctly inserted in the BD. But as soon as I un-comment those, I get just 1 record inserted, while the value stored in "c" is the last element in the collection (so the loop worked fine).

I also tried calling `commandStatement.Parameters.Clear()` right after the `commandStatement.ExecuteNonQuery()` sentence, but that makes no difference (and it shouldn't, but I still tried).

I don't want to make things complicated by using transactions and such, if I can avoid them, since this is a very simple, single-computer, offline and small application. So if anyone knows what I could do to make that code work, I'd be very grateful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here: `commandStatement.CommandText = queryGetLastId;` you actually changing your command from inserting to selecting identity.

Thus, on the next iteration it will not insert anything, but again select for identity, that's why you're having only one record inserted into DB.

I think it's better to have two separate commands for inserting and for selecting identity.

Also note - you're trying to add new parameter into `commandStatement` on each iteration, so on iteration, say, N it will be N parameters. Either clear parameters before adding new one, or add parameter outside of loop and in the loop change its value only.

```
using (OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(strDeConexion))
{
    using (OleDbCommand commandStatement = new OleDbCommand(queryInsertTable1, dbConnection))
    using (OleDbCommand commandIdentity = new OleDbCommand(queryGetLastId , dbConnection))
    {    
        commandStatement.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter());

        dbConnection.Open();
        foreach (int c in Collection)
        {
            commandStatement.Parameters[0].Value = c;
            commandStatement.ExecuteNonQuery();

            LastInsertedId = (int)commandIdentity.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about adding `commandStatement.CommandText = queryInsertTable1` at the start of `foreach`?

Comment: @MikeDebela well, it is possible. But I still think having two separate commands is better. Otherwise you need to reassign back and forth parameters, command text and so on - this makes code much less readable.

Comment: Darn! I knew it had to be something silly :P
Too much programming and too little sleep!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Once you changed the commandtext the first query is gone from it so it wont insert any data to the first table again. reassing it and try